# MySQL Query Not Returning Values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get values from MySQL database where the value of the Username column is the same as the parameter being passed in. The parameter being passed in is "Griffin".

```
function logIntoDb($username)
{
$users = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], "SELECT Id, Username FROM Users WHERE $username=Username");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users))
{
echo "\"Match: " . $row['Id'] . "=" . $row['Username'] . "\"";
echo " - " . ($username==$row['Username'] ? "true" : "false");
echo "<br/>";
}
}
```

The above keeps returning an empty result, which causes my while loop to throw this warning.

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a654/public_html/Top/Bottom/log.php on line 16

Here is the Users table:

```
Id|CreatedOn|Username|Info|Status|Rank|Total|

1|0000-00-00 00:00:00|Peter|123|Good|High|111.11

2|0000-00-00 00:00:00|Griffin|123|Bad|Low|000.00
```

Is there something that I am not seeing that prevents the Griffin row from being returned?

Comment: It should be the other way around like this... `"SELECT Id, Username FROM Users WHERE Username='$username'"`

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.  **Learn how to do it right before the bad habits become part of your thinking.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be `"SELECT Id, Username FROM Users WHERE '$username'=Username"`

You need the single quotes since it's a string and not a number.

Comment: Let's say I had two parameter called $id and $time; the $id that is being passed will be a numeric value and the $time that is being passed will be an numeric value (representing the number of seconds). There respective values in the database are type int(11). If I was to compare the parameter with the value in the database like I did above, would I still have to use single quotes since it isn't a string?

Comment: No, if both are int types, you do not need single quotes.  You only have to use single quotes to encapsulate a string.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the apostrophes around the username. Change this:

```
"SELECT Id, Username FROM Users WHERE $username=Username"
```

Into this:

```
"SELECT Id, Username FROM Users WHERE '$username'=Username"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace $username to '$username' provided everything else is fine